# Passing variables Through Javascript in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, function, variables, cordova

I am trying to pass a variable between two functions , 
in my first function i am appending Html to contain a specific ID within a loop
each loop provides my ID with the correct information.

```
<a class="item" href="#" onClick="function(' + id +')"> + data + </a>
```

in my second i am trying to retrieve this ID in order to complete and SQL query to retrieve valid information.

I have tried to Declare the variable globally, and pass it in the function declaration.

```
    function new func(id) { 
        console.log("The value of ID is = " + id);
            cd.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = "'+ id +"'");
        }
```

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please provide more context for these methods (ie, the code that surrounds them)

Comment: Your function definition is not valid, try `function func(id)` and `onClick="func(' + id +')"`

Comment: Even if the function definition becomes valid and the proper function name is used in the onclick handler, the handler will pass the exact string ` + id +`, not just the id. Check your quotes.